# Trying to Run middleman on mac

Tags: ruby, macos, clang, eventmachine, middleman

Answering my own question for anyone else having this issue. (using the search terms i thought of because they didn't bring up the answers for me).

Trying to install and run middleman following the getting started guide on their website with Mac OS X 10.9.2. When trying to run bundle install getting errors about openSSL and event machine.

[Gist of Errors.](https://gist.github.com/timgauthier/10384291)

[Refrence to an answer that someone on IRC helped me find.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908484/getting-eventmachine-gem-to-compile-on-osx-lion-10-8-2-with-xcode-4-5-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparently this is caused by a mismatch in expected versions with something called Clang which is part of the Xcode tools for mac. The update to Xcode tools causes this to fail. Using the command:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future bundle install
```

seems to work to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have come back to this page to copy this command several times in the past week as it comes up that often. Hopefully CLANG and Xcode can work out their differences soon.